# Retrieve max column value in a table from java

Tags: sql, select, jdbc, derby, resultset

i am trying to retrieve the max value of the column ID from the table SAMPLE_1. i am able to execute the sql query in Derby but i am not able to retrieve the value from my result set in java. Am i doing something wrong? do i need to retrieve the value from the max function in another way? Please help.

```
selectQuery = dbConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT MAX(ID) 
                                               FROM ROOTUSER.SAMPLE_1");
resultSet = selectQuery.executeQuery();

System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `resultSet.next()` before calling `getString()`.

Comment: You are not bad, just maybe unexperienced.

Answer (score 0):

example

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE age IN (SELECT MAX(age) age FROM Employee)
```